# onCreateView is called before fragment created

Tags: android, fragment

My app uses `PagerView` component to display some data.Each tab is a fragment.In the app there is facebook authorization which occurs in the separate activity.
The problem is when user has insufficient memory android kills app's activity and when he returns after authorization android tries to restart activity and something weird happens here.To simulate such condition I set maximum number of background processes to 0.Here is log when I start app from scratch:

> tabs: adapter created
>   fragment: onCreateView view:android.widget.FrameLayout{195756ef V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0},fragment:CategoryFragment{128705fc #0 id=0x7f1000f0 android:switcher:2131755248:0}
>   fragment: onstart android.widget.FrameLayout{195756ef V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0},view:android.widget.FrameLayout{195756ef V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0},fragment:CategoryFragment{128705fc #0 id=0x7f1000f0 android:switcher:2131755248:0}

Everything looks good so far(fragment is created within tab adapter and then onCreateView is called).And here what happens after I log in into facebook and return to the app:

> fragment: onDestroyView
>   fragment: onDestroy
>   fragment: onCreateView view:android.widget.FrameLayout{f50f881 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0},fragment:CategoryFragment{25f74d26 #0 id=0x7f1000f0 android:switcher:2131755248:0}
>   fragment: onstart android.widget.FrameLayout{f50f881 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0},view:android.widget.FrameLayout{f50f881 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0},fragment:CategoryFragment{25f74d26 #0 id=0x7f1000f0 android:switcher:2131755248:0}
>   tabs: adapter created

How could it be that fragment's view is created before the fragment?
Tabs adapter class:

```
private class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private CategoryFragment fragment1;
    private PackFragment fragment2;
    private HistoryFragment fragment3;
    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
        Log.d("fragment","tabs adapter created");
        fragment1=new CategoryFragment();
        fragment2=new PackFragment();
        fragment3=new HistoryFragment();
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Log.d("get item",position+"");
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return fragment1;
            case 1:
                return fragment2;
            case 2:
                return fragment3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Here how its instantiated:

```
   //after some initialization stuff
   tabs=(PuzzlePagerView) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
   tabs.setCurrentItem(0,false);
   tabs.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
   FragmentManager fm=this.getSupportFragmentManager();
   tabs.setAdapter(new TabsAdapter(fm));
```

Comment: You are giving us some of the logs. That's great. However, can you also give some of the code you are mentioning? Ex. show your adapter code and where and how your set the adapter to viewpager

Comment: sorry, added  adapter's code.The code is canonical.

Comment: i suspect your fragments are not being destroyed

Comment: is there a reason you are creating each fragment before `getItem` is even called? Just call it in `getItem`. Ex. `return new CategoryFragment();` or `return new PackFragment();`

Comment: and my fragment will be recreated each time getItem is called?Don't think its good idea

Comment: @rupps fragment before login: `CategoryFragment{128705fc #0 id=0x7f1000f0 android:switcher:2131755248:0}`, after:`CategoryFragment{25f74d26 #0 id=0x7f1000f0 android:switcher:2131755248:0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was is that android tries to restore activity state along with all its fragments.

```
super.onCreate(null);
```

in the activity class solved all issues.